# How do I get notification that the local Visual Studio build is complete?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build

There doesn't seem to be a post-build solution task.  One could presumably hack it by creating a dummy project that is the last one to build and put a beep in the post-build project.

Comment: Are you talking about TFS build or just a build on your local machine?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Do you need something like [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/rrobbins/archive/2007/11/02/sound-events-for-visual-studio.aspx) (screenshot is there)?

> Did you know you can assign sounds to a few Visual Studio events? You can assign a WAV file to play when a build fails or succeeds. Just open the Control Panel, select Sounds and Audio Devices and then click the Sounds tab. Scroll down to Microsoft Development Environment. I assigned my Build Succeeded to a WAV file of Darth Vader saying "All Too Easy" and my Build Failed to a WAV file of Han Solo saying "I got a bad feeling about this."

Comment: That is awesome! Even better!

Comment: Visual Studio has to be restarted after changing those settings.

Answer (score 5):

There is Visual Studio Ding extension.

> This small extension will play notification sounds when following
>   events occur:
>
> - Build Complete
>
>   - Entering debugger mode (breakpoint hit, etc)
>   - Unit tests finished to run

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/941d0ed0-1218-452e-8585-d3ac693cda17

Comment: This extension also shows a notification on the system tray!

Answer (score 4):

The [ToastNotifier Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7aa63d6e-5701-40e4-9b91-9039a7d6ba26) seems to work well for visual feedback.

Comment: @BornToCode no, Toast Notifications were added in Windows 8.

Comment: This is the extension I went with. Working perfectly on Win10/VS2017.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Start -> Control Panel -> Sounds and Audio Devices. Then on the Sounds tab you'll find a set of sounds for Microsoft Visual Studio in the Program Events list.  You can attach a sound to build finishing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can also now as of VS2019 gain access to the system sounds through the UI. Go Options->Test.

You can also find more info out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/run-unit-tests-with-test-explorer?view=vs-2019#test-audio-cue

[image: System sounds hook in Visual Studio]

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple .bat file that you could add to the post-build events...

Here a link: [Pre-build Event/Post-build Event Command Line Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have used [this](http://devlicious.com/blogs/christopher_bennage/archive/2009/08/27/build-notification-visual-studio-amp-snarl.aspx).
It's pretty neat for visual notification, while the options posted by others are all fine for audio.

Comment: this is the link from Download.com
http://download.cnet.com/Snarl/3000-2384_4-10767294.html

Comment: Actually the latest releases of the Ding extension also shows a visual notification on system tray.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I just have the "Output" window turn on by default and don't use the task list. This way I can see what it is doing at all times. I find the messages from this window to be much more enlightening than the task/error list.

Comment: On the other hand, on the "Output" window you can easily miss warnings  in your code. I use the "Output" window because of it's more detailed nature, too, but lately got used to check the Task/Error list afterwards to see if there were warnings. (It would be great if the tab header would indicate the number of errors, warnings and notifications, looking like "Task list (0/3/0)" or similar)

Comment: Haha. compling a cpp project with cinder/boost/std + computer vision libraries you get hundreds of warnings, making the output pretty useless during compile.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Growl with visual studio add on](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/plugins/visualstudio). It's also working with VS2013 by using [this tweak](http://www.alexdresko.com/2014/03/28/growl-for-windows-visual-studio-2013/).

Comment: This URL is dead.