# Make a silly sound when build succeeds

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I was thinking of adding a 'Post build' step, which plays a silly fan fair effect when a build succeeds.

Is there a command line utility to play the sound effect or an easier way of achieving this vital programming goal!

Comment: +1 for this "vital programming goal". I'd want to hear "HADOKEN!"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get Visual Studio to beep at me if a build succeeds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629125/how-can-i-get-visual-studio-to-beep-at-me-if-a-build-succeeds)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio IDE: I want it to make a sound after it compiles so I can get back to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836947/visual-studio-ide-i-want-it-to-make-a-sound-after-it-compiles-so-i-can-get-back)

Comment: What is the point of this?  Would it not make sense to play a dirge when the build fails? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also take a look at this since it is actually an older duplicate of your question with more sugestions that might just work:

[How can I get Visual Studio to beep at me if a build succeeds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629125/how-can-i-get-visual-studio-to-beep-at-me-if-a-build-succeeds)

For VS 2008 and newer you should look at this (some people mention they have the options in Sounds and Audio Devices dialog with 2005 SP1 installed while others say with 2005 it never works/worked- but who knows maybe you just get lucky ;-)):

http://weblogs.asp.net/rrobbins/archive/2007/11/02/sound-events-for-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: I sometimes feel that unless I'm asking a 'please do my job for me' type question, that's bound to happen!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind the Windows Media Player popping up (and staying open), you could either try

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" foo.wav
```

or

```
start foo.wav
```

Or I guess you would have to use a custom sound [player](http://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch04.html) (or [build your own](http://www.mailsend-online.com/blog/a-command-line-mp3-player-for-windows.html)).

Answer (score 2):

There is Visual Studio Ding extension.

> This small extension will play notification sounds when following
>   events occur:
>
> Build Complete
>
> Entering debugger mode (breakpoint hit, etc)   Unit tests finished to
>   run

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/941d0ed0-1218-452e-8585-d3ac693cda17

Answer (score 1):

you could use command line audio players like http://www.mpg123.de/