# Make Sound When Command Line Completes

Tags: bash

This may sound like a silly little think (maybe it is haha), but I was thinking it would be great for my command line to be able to let me know when it's done running instead of me continually checking.

Specifically, when it completes deploying my project to firebase via the following line:

```
firebase deploy
```

**Is playing a sound after my command line completes possible?**

For reference, I was able to find something similar for ubuntu [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498025/make-a-silly-sound-when-build-succeeds).

*As a side note, it'd be extra awesome if the solution could be set up to play a custom sound of my own and/or could work for when `npm run build` completes as well*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30016842/2836621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 'say'

```
$ command && say 'task finished'
```

Comment: `say` is standard on macOS but on many other platforms you will need to install some speech synthesis package.

Comment: @Andy Ray. This worked perfectly for me and was far simpler than the solutions linked in the "duplicate" (whoops, sorry).  +1 as this also allowed me to combine my `npm run build` command and `firebase deploy` command into one (like so `npm run build && firebase deploy && say 'task finished`), rather than me taking action in between the two!  Truly wonderful. Thank you!

Comment: the problem with this  approach is that notification works only if the first command passes, the reason is the way && is implemented in shell, it stops once prev cmd fails.

Comment: Then replace `&&` with `;`

Answer (score 0):

I guess "Make Sound" can be any notification mechanism. If `zenity` is available, you could do something like :

```
firebase deploy
#At this point, you would like to be notified.
zenity --info --text="Firebase deployment complete" 2>/dev/null
```

You ll get something like

[image: This dialogue]