# VS 2019 makes a sound every time I type braces

Tags: audio, visual-studio-2019, braces

VS 2019 is making a sound every time I type open or close brace. I hate it. I have searched everywhere, in system settings, VS menus, google, etc etc and I just can't figure out how to disable this idiotic feature. I can't be possible that others aren't annoyed by this! Please help.

Comment: News to me. Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710384/10871073) offer any help?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't VS2019. It was Discord. Even though it was running as a tool tray app, for some horrible reason Discord was making all of the following keys cause a sound to play: { } [ ]